# Multiple Api request using RxJava and Retrofit

Tags: retrofit, rx-java

I fetch list of popular movies from the remote server using Retrofit and RxJava. Every movie has some info but I need more info about movie and I can do it with another request with passing movie_id and I receive more info about movie which id I passed. For exemple I need movie's genre but from first movie info request I have only ids of geners, if I will make another request using movie id I will get more info about movie and there is list of objects with genrs and their ids. How can I combine two requests in one object?

data of first request
[image]

data of second request where I pass movie_id and get genres
[image]

code from repository where I make request for movie with less info

```
class MoviesRepositoryImpl(
    private val schedulersIO: Scheduler,
    private val moviesApi: MoviesApi,
    private val moviesApiMapper: MoviesApiMapper
): MoviesRepository {

    override fun getPopularMovies(): Single<List<PopularMovieModel>> {
        return moviesApi.getPopularMovies()
            .subscribeOn(schedulersIO)
            .map { moviesApiMapper.mapPopularMoviesApiToModelList(it) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatMap` operator with 2 parameters for this purposes:

```
getPopularMovies()
    .map { 
        it[0] // get respective movie, in this case I just get a first movie in the list 
    }.flatMap( {  
        movie ->  api.getMovieDetails(movie.id) //request for movie details 
            }, { movie, details ->  DetailedMovieModel(movie, description)}
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution

```
  private fun getPopularMovies(): Single<List<Result>> {
        return moviesApi.getPopularMovies()
            .map { it.results }

    }

    private fun getMovieDetailsList(): Single<List<MovieDetailsModelApi>> {

        return moviesApi.getPopularMovies().toObservable()
            .flatMapIterable {
                it.results
            }
            .flatMap {
                moviesApi.getMoviesDetails(it.id).toObservable()

            }
            .toList()
    }

   override fun getMoviesWithDetails() :Single<List<PopularMovieWithDetailsModel>>{
        return Single.zip(getPopularMovies(),getMovieDetailsList()) { movieList, detailsList ->
            moviesApiMapper.mapMovieDetailsAndMoviesToModelList(detailsList, movieList)
        }
            .subscribeOn(schedulersIO)

    }
```